# query took too much time to load

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 ( SELECT 'no' AS aff,
         ss.orderid, ss.secondaff, ss.saletype, ss.price,
         ss.affiliate, ss.vendor,
         ss.cpa,ss.rebill,ss.salests,ss.fname,ss.lname 
    FROM sales ss 
   WHERE 1=1
     AND ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade') 
ORDER BY ss.salests DESC ) 
  UNION ALL 
 (   SELECT 'yes' AS aff, ss.orderid,ss.secondaff,ss.saletype,sf.price,
            ss.affiliate,ss.vendor,ss.cpa,ss.rebill,ss.salests,ss.fname,ss.lname 
       FROM salesaff sf 
      INNER JOIN sales ss ON ss.orderid=sf.orderid 
      WHERE 1=1 
        AND ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade') 
   ORDER BY sf.salests DESC ) 
ORDER BY salests DESC
```

I need to select data from sales table with given condition, and select data from  `salesaff` table too if vendor=affiliate in sales table and ss.orderid=sf=orderid in above sql.

I wrote this with some help but query took 195 sec to load. `sales table` contains 8000 rows and index by salests,vendor,affiliate,orderid. The `salesaff` table contains 6000 rows and is indexed by orderid

Both table contains same columns.

Some facts:
-> If i remove custom column from both ('yes' as aff, 'no' as aff), then query will execute if i use limit 100 or something. Otherwise it takes 195 sec to load.

If i use limit 100, then query is executed in 2 sec. But without limiting, it gives error code 500.
Moreover, I need total sum of price too. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you missing opening bracket in the begining?(I'm sure it is a typo and not solves the question btw)

Comment: For the sake both of your own understanding and courtesy to us on StackOverflow, please consider editing your SQL queries so the line breaks help display your logic.

Comment: yeah sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first efficiency is that the order by in the subqueries is not necessary, unless you are putting limit clauses there. So try this:

```
(SELECT 'no' AS aff, ss.orderid, ss.secondaff, ss.saletype, ss.price, ss.affiliate, 
         ss.vendor, ss. cpa, ss.rebill, ss.salests, ss.fname, ss.lname 
 FROM sales ss 
 WHERE 1=1 AND ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade')
) 
UNION ALL 
( SELECT 'yes' AS aff, ss.orderid, ss.secondaff, ss.saletype, sf.price, ss.affiliate, 
         ss.vendor, ss.cpa, ss.rebill, ss.salests, ss.fname, ss.lname 
 FROM salesaff sf INNER JOIN
      sales ss
      ON ss.orderid = sf.orderid 
 WHERE 1=1 AND ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade') 
 ) 
ORDER BY salests DESC
```

Comment: Oh no, seems I edited yours too. Sorry. Maybe a bug in SO. Something weird happened.

Comment: Error in Processing Request
Error Code: 500
Error text: Internal Server Error. Exactly same as earlier. If i use limit 100 then data will display in 2 sec.

Comment: @user3144629 . . . Try running the query directly on the database.

Comment: Yes i ran directly from phpmyadmin. If i add "limit 100", then query takes 2 sec to execute. Without limit, i am getting the error above, 500 error code.

Comment: @user3144629 . . . Do you get the same error without the final `order by`?

Comment: Exactly same error . "Error in Processing Request       Error Code: 500          Error text: Internal Server Error."

Comment: @user3144629 . . . In that case, I suspect the problem is in the volume of data being passed from the database back to the application.  Not sure that doing anything to the query will help, unless you know that some of the columns are extremely long.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46085/discussion-between-user3144629-and-gordon-linoff)

Answer (score 1):

Heh heh. This is a hard one. You're probably getting correct results, but your hosting provider is timing out your query, so you can't tell.  These two tables don't seem very large to me.

First, increase the timeout time if you can, especially for debugging. It's difficult to ensure correctness if your inefficient queries don't finish. The most efficient query in the world is worthless if it's wrong. Ask your hosting provider support person for help.

Second, you will get a timeout if it takes too long for the query to complete and return the first row of the resultset. You might also get a timeout if your host language is slow to consume the entire resultset, so make sure you're doing that efficiently.

Third, let's break it down. You're looking up a particular set of sales records. You're doing an OR operation.  Most likely that guarantees a full table scan, which isn't so good for performance.

You may as well skip the `1=1` in your `WHERE` clauses. That's usually put in there as a hack to make the construction of code by a host language a little simpler. It shouldn't hurt performance, but it won't help.

Making a couple of guesses: assuming `ss.orderid` is a unique (autoincrement) primary key field, you might try adding compound indexes -- covering indexes -- on

```
   (vendor, orderid)
```

and

```
   (affiliate,orderid)
```

then using the following query to retrieve the list of orderid values you need to look up.

```
         SELECT orderid FROM sales WHERE vendor = '3kpertrade'
          UNION
         SELECT orderid FROM sales WHERE affiliate = '3kpertrade'
```

This subquery efficiently looks up the set of `orderid` values you need. The two covering indexes I suggested will improve performance pretty significantly.  (Don't use `UNION ALL` here, use `UNION`, or you may get some duplicated data.)

Then you can use this query to get some of your order data -- the first part of your `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT 'no' AS aff,
       ss.orderid, ss.secondaff, ss.saletype, ss.price,
       ss.affiliate, ss.vendor,
       ss.cpa,ss.rebill,ss.salests,ss.fname,ss.lname 
  FROM sales ss 
  JOIN (
         SELECT orderid FROM sales WHERE vendor = '3kpertrade'
          UNION
         SELECT orderid FROM sales WHERE affiliate = '3kpertrade'
       ) ids ON ss.orderid = ids.orderid
```

I suggest you debug your app with just this much of your query. Make sure it's displaying the correct stuff.

You appear to be implementing a shadow-booking system in your query. That is, when a particular order appears in your `salesaff` table you're *duplicating* it in this query's result set. It looks like the only information you retrieve from `salesaff` is the price.  Is that correct? Do affiliate sales show up more than once in your `UNION ALL` result set?

Along these same lines, second half of your query will look like this:

```
SELECT 'yes' AS aff, ss.orderid, ss.secondaff, ss.saletype,
        sf.price,
        ss.affiliate, ss.vendor, ss.cpa, ss.rebill, ss.salests, ss.fname, ss.lname 
  FROM sales AS ss 
  JOIN (
         SELECT orderid FROM sales WHERE vendor = '3kpertrade'
          UNION
         SELECT orderid FROM sales WHERE affiliate = '3kpertrade'
       ) ids ON ss.orderid = ids.orderid 
  JOIN salesaff sf ON ss.orderid=sf.orderid
```

If the only information you're pulling from `salesaff` is in fact the price, then a covering index

```
 (orderid, price)
```

will help this query a bit.

Finally, do the UNION ALL and the `ORDER BY`.

An observation.  If `sales.salests` is a timestamp, and if `sales.orderid` is an auto-incrementing index, and if you never update `sales.salests` but only insert it, then `ORDER BY orderid DESC` will do the same thing as `ORDER BY salests DESC`. That might save a little time.

Comment: i loved your answer and answering style. Finally i made it working with little modification in your response. I joined data of same table sales and retrieved price only from salesaff. It is working now. Thank you very much for your support. I love it.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably completely simplify by going through the table once and doing a left-join to the salesaff table.  Then case/when for your yes/no status

I would have an index on ( vendor, aaffiliate, salests )

```
SELECT 
      CASE when sf.orderid is null 
           then 'no' else 'yes' end AS aff,
      ss.orderid, 
      ss.secondaff, 
      ss.saletype, 
      ss.price,
      ss.affiliate, 
      ss.vendor,
      ss.cpa,
      ss.rebill,
      ss.salests,
      ss.fname,
      ss.lname 
   FROM 
      sales ss
         LEFT JOIN salesaff sf 
            ON ss.orderid=sf.orderid 
   WHERE
         ss.vendor = '3kpertrade' 
      OR ss.affiliate = '3kpertrade'
   ORDER BY 
      ss.salests DESC
```

Comment: . . My interpretation of the question is that the OP wants both all the sales and then the affiliates too.

Comment: orderid can't be null. Both table have same columns but salesaff should be selected (union) when vendor=affiliate in sales. I need to track the row from which table its retrieved so used select 'no'/'yes' as aff. I don't think we can handle by left/right join at all.

Comment: Yes Gordon Correct. This query is insufficient as it only selects from one table.